# Display Woocommerce Related Products By Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I want to display related products based on Custom taxonomy. Is there a way to force related products to be displayed based on Custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'prfx_change_related_products_count' );
function prfx_change_related_products_count( $args ) {

// Current post as global
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'your_custom_taxonomy' );

// Empty array
$ids = array();

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    array_push($ids, $term->term_id);
}

 $args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'your_custom_taxonomy',
    'terms' => $ids,
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'include_children' => true,
    'operator' => 'IN'
  )
);

 return $args;
}
```

Comment: Hi Brother, after adding this code to function.php it's getting " There has been a critical error on this website. " error.

Comment: @liaz Ahmed can you share a screenshot or error code for understand ?

Comment: It was missing ; for $args['tax_query'] .